# JavaFX reset graphics Context after scaling a canvas

Tags: graphics, javafx, overlay

I'm trying to make a chart without using any 3rd party libs. I've a zoom feature which scales the Canvas correctly, but now I need to redraw everything inside the canvas once again.

But when I do scaling the `GrapphicsContext` also scales and blots. I want to readjust the blotting and show points in normal drawing once zoomed. How can I achieve this?

Here is simple snippet that I'm redrawing:

```
private void redrawImage(Canvas canvas, int scale) {
      GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
      gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      gc.scale(scale, scale);
      gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
      gc.setLineWidth(2);
      gc.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      gc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
      gc.strokeLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      gc.strokeLine(0, canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), 0);
      gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
      gc.strokeText("TEXT", 50, 50);

  }
```

Even I remove `gc.scale(X,Y)` I still see the blotted points or text, I want the scale to be always 1, but I should also zoom or scale simultaneously.

What I want to achieve is like the **GoogleMaps** overlaying, you see the objects when zoomed in or out are recalibrated and adjusted to a viewable scale. This is exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correct.

Your redrawImage method should get an double and not an int value for the scale. Even if you try to scale to 1.9 the cast from double to int will bring it down to 1.

I've made a little example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100, 100);
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(100, 100);

    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, canvas2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    redrawImage(canvas, 0.5);
    redrawImage(canvas2, 1);
  }

  private void redrawImage(Canvas canvas, double scale) {
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    gc.scale(scale, scale);
    gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
    gc.setLineWidth(2);
    gc.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    gc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
    gc.strokeLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    gc.strokeLine(0, canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), 0);
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    gc.strokeText("TEXT", 50, 50);
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

}
```

With the following result:

[image]

Comment: Agreed about scaling, But the thing is as you notice the `TEXT` is blotted and not the same as viewable scale.

What I want to achieve is like the GoogleMaps overlaying, you see the objects when zoomed are recalibrated and adjusted. This is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Ah, you want to set the text size in relation to scale level? But not beyond a fixed value, so that it is always readable?

Comment: Yes. Not only text. I've objects like filled circles, rectangles as well, which will need to resize accordingly.

Comment: @zIronManBox In my opinion this is not the correct approach to do it with canvas and GraphicsContext. You may want more like playing with camera. This could be done by Transform and Translate. Visit this tutorial to get a knowledge of what could be done: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/transformations-intro.htm#sthref9

Comment: That tutorial only shows scaling and not resizing after zoom, I require adjustment after scaling inside the canvas.

Comment: And do you happen to know how you can select an object inside a canvas of javaFX?

Comment: @zIronManBox As I mentioned above, this is not a correct way of doing it to me. You should look at this project to get a knowledge of what is possible and what not. https://bitbucket.org/limetri/mapviewer/overview